# Mastering external scripts loading order in Meteor (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

I tried unsuccessfully to add a google map(externally loaded script) to a meteor app, and I noticed there were two kinds of problems:

1. If I do the simple thing and add the main API script to my `<head></head>`, then it gets rendered **last**.
2. When this happens, I am obliged to insert any scripts that **depend** on the API again in my template's `<head>` - after the main API script. (otherwise scripts complain they don't see the API blabla..)
3. Then the time for the actually function call comes - and now putting it inside `<head>` after the rest won't work. You need to use Template.MyTemplate.rendered.

Basically my question is:

- What's the cleanest way to handle these kinds of things?
- Is there some other variable/method I can use to make sure my Google main API file is called very first in my HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by `This causes a problem for the plugin I use to abstract the API` when you put the call inside `<head></head>`?

Comment: Well I'm using the "Gmaps.js" plugin that simplifies how you do stuff with the Google API... One of these libraries.. That usually are on top of jQuery.. And it doesn't work because of the loading order of Meteor. That's the basic problem - I should simplify my question I think.

Comment: Georges, can you link to a pastebin or a github repo with a code sample?

Comment: it's a theoretical question so not much to paste in a pastebin..

Comment: It's interesting how a framework going around as the grand pooba of making development easy makes it such an itch to do simple things like file includes. I am trying to figure our a way to do this without doing something horribly unelegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just released a package on atmosphere (https://atmosphere.meteor.com) that might help a bit.  It's called session-extras, and it defines a couple functions that I've used to help with integrating external scripts.  Code here: https://github.com/belisarius222/meteor-session-extras

The basic idea is to load a script asynchronously, and then in the callback when the script has finished loading, set a Session variable.  I use the functions in the session-extras package to try to make this process a bit smoother.  I have a few functions that have 3 or 4 different dependencies (scripts and subscriptions), so it was starting to get hairy...

I suppose I should add that you can then conditionally render templates based on whether all the dependencies are there.  So if you have a facebook button, for example, with helpers that check the Session variables, you can give it a "disabled" css class and show "loading facebook..." until all the necessary scripts have loaded.

**edit 03/14/2013**

There is also an entirely different approach that is applicable in many cases: create your own package.  This is currently possible with Meteorite [(instructions)](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/package), and the functionality should soon be available in Meteor itself.  Some examples of this approach are:

- jquery-rate-it: https://github.com/dandv/meteor-jquery-rateit
- meteor-mixpanel: https://github.com/belisarius222/meteor-mixpanel

If you put a js file in a package, it loads before your app code, which is often a good way to include libraries.  Another advantage of making a package is that packages can declare dependencies on each other, so if the script in question is, for example, a jQuery plugin, you can specify in the package's `package.js` file that the package depends on jQuery, and that will ensure the correct load order.

Sometimes it gets a little more interesting (in the Chinese curse sense), since many external services, including mixpanel and filepicker.io, have a 2-part loading process: 1) a JS snippet to be included at the end of the body, and 2) a bigger script loaded from a CDN asynchronously by that snippet.  The js snippet generally (but not always!) makes some methods available for use before the  bigger script loads, so that you can call its functions without having to set up more logic to determine its load status.  Mixpanel does that, although it's important to remember that some of the JS snippets from external services expect you to set the API key at the end of the snippet, guaranteed to be before the bigger script loads; in some cases if the script loads before the API key is set, the library won't function correctly.  See the meteor-mixpanel package for an example of an attempt at a workaround.

It's possible to simply download the bigger js file yourself from the CDN and stick it in your application; however, there are good reasons not to do this: 
1) the hosted code might change, and unless you check it religiously, your code could get out of date and start to use an old version of the API
2) these libraries have usually been optimized to load the snippet quickly in a way that doesn't increase your page load time dramatically.  If you include the bigger JS file in your application, then your server has to serve it, not a CDN, and it will serve it on initial page  load.

Comment: I didn't have time to implement it yet but it seems to be the solution to the problem. However I haven't used atmosphere yet (TBH first time I hear about it) but by looking at things if I understand correctly it's not an "official" Meteor package, right? (don't know if that matters)

Comment: I highly recommend using Meteorite; it's Meteor's de facto package manager, and I've never had any bugs with it.  Meteor is really young, so there's a lot of functionality that hasn't made it into core yet and that you really shouldn't have to write yourself.  The Meteor team is working on their own package manager at the moment, which is based at least partly on Meteorite, and the packages should be mostly compatible.  If you don't want to use Meteorite, feel free to take the js file from my repo and put that in your project in a "client" folder.

Comment: I should mention that it's also quite possible to take the same approach without the session-extras library or Meteorite or anything.  Set Session variables in callbacks when scripts finish loading, then run a function in a Deps.autorun() that checks whether all the Session variables have been set to what they need to be and runs the dependent code once everything's there.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're loading your Javascript files by linking it with HTML in your template. There's a more Meteor way of doing this:

From the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/):

> Meteor gathers all JavaScript files in your tree with the exception of
>   the server and public subdirectories for the client. It minifies this
>   bundle and serves it to each new client. You're free to use a single
>   JavaScript file for your entire application, or create a nested tree
>   of separate files, or anything in between.

So with that in mind, rather than link the gmaps.js into head, just download the un-minified version of gmaps and drop it in you application's tree.

Also from the Meteor Docs:

> It is best to write your application in such a way that it is
>   insensitive to the order in which files are loaded, for example by
>   using Meteor.startup, or by moving load order sensitive code into
>   Smart Packages, which can explicitly control both the load order of
>   their contents and their load order with respect to other packages.
>   However sometimes load order dependencies in your application are
>   unavoidable. The JavaScript and CSS files in an application are loaded
>   according to these rules:
>
> **Files in the lib directory at the root of your application are loaded
>   first.**
>   *[emphasis added]*

And if the sequence is still an issue, drop the js file into `client/lib` and it will load before all the Javascript you've written.

Comment: A script hosted on a remote host or CDN is commonly already cached by the browser, particularly for popular scripts like jquery or gmaps. Downloading these into your project will negate this benefit, increasing the time for initial site load.

Answer (score 1):

I've used meteor-external-file-loader and a bit of asynchronous looping to load some scripts, which will load javascript (or stylesheets) in the order you specify.

Make sure to have meteorite and add the package above  >> mrt add external-file-loader

Here's the function I wrote to make use of this package:

```
var loadFiles = function(files, callback) {
  if (!callback) callback = function() {};

  (function step(files, timeout, callback) {
    if (!files.length) return callback();

    var loader;
    var file = files.shift();
    var extension = file.split(".").pop();
    if (extension === "js")
      loader = Meteor.Loader.loadJs(file, function() {}, timeout);
    else if (extension === "css") {
      Meteor.Loader.loadCss(file);
      loader = $.Deferred().resolve();
    }
    else {
      return step(files, timeout, callback);
    }

    loader.done(function() {
      console.log("Loaded: " + file);
      step(files, timeout, callback);
    }).fail(function() {
      console.error("Failed to load: " + file);
      step(files, timeout, callback);
    });
  })(files, 5000, callback);
}
```

Then to use this, add to one of your created methods for a template like so:

```
Template.yourpage.created = function() {
  var files = [
    "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"
  ];

  loadFiles(files, function() {
    console.log("Scripts loaded!");
  });
}
```

Quick edit: Found it's just a good idea to place the functionality from the .created method in the /lib folder in Meteor.startup();

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // Load files here.
  }
});
```

Caveat: Lots of javascript files = really long load time.... Not sure how that will be affected by the normal meteor javascript files, and the load order there. I would just make sure that there are no conflicts until users take action on the website (or that if there is, they are loaded first).